# Disabling the autostart of a service from /etc/init.d without disabling the service?

Tags: boot, init, init-script

I have a service that gets started via /etc/init.d at boot and that cause the final steps of the boot processes to be delayed long enough that it's possible to log in via the graphic display manager before everything is set up properly.

The culprit is netatalk which is a service that I don't need that often.

Does init support a multi-tier approach to have certain services started in a second round (and how)? Or will I have to disable the auto-starting-at-boot and launch the service manually or at the end of rc.local (`/etc/init.d/netatalk start`)?

As far as I know it's possible only to disable the service via `/etc/default/netatalk` but maybe I'm missing something (outside of changing the netatalk init script itself)?

FWIW, I'm not running the legacy `atalkd` daemon which could be launched in the background (option in /etc/default/netatalk).

EDIT: I forgot to mention a crucial detail. This is Kubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. I know it's no longer in support but that's not the point here and I have my reasons not to upgrade to a completely new version. I keep the kernels updated, X, Mesa, DRM drivers are all updated to give optimum performance but most of the core OS is still Ubuntu 14.04 with its somewhat strange combination of `upstart` (provides /sbin/init) and parts of `systemd` which play only a minor role as far as I can tell.

Many of the scripts in /etc/init.d have corresponding entries in /etc/init which is definitely used by upstart.

As mentioned in the discussion below I have tweaked the netatalk init script so it starts all services in the background if the backgrounding option is set in /etc/default/netatalk. That aside think my main "problem" is that I do things in /etc/rc.local that should be finished before anyone logs into a desktop session. That script is always executed last as far as I understand so it seems my best option is not to rely on the init system for deferring slowly-starting services but to prevent them from being started automatically and the start them "manually" in a post-amble section of /etc/rc.local .

So my question becomes: does upstart provide a way to do disable autostart without disabling the service altogether?

Comment: Please do add the information on your boot system that you gave in your comments under my answer to your question! They are crucial to answerers. Since I suspect "FrankUbuntu" is something relatively unknow, you'll have to explicitly tell us the name of this boot system, and if possible, link to some documentation. It doesn't seem to be sysv-init, you say it's not systemd, so, what is it?

Comment: openrc ? In case of positive answer, yes ! there is a way. Please post the output of rc-update show

Comment: Thanks, and I wish. No `rc-update` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is utterly believable, and your request for your graphical system to start before netatalk has finished starting is utterly sensible – it's not a dependency, and should not delay starting the graphical login manager. Your system should make it possibly for you to start doing what you need as early as possible.

That is literally the job of a boot / service manager: to make sure the services are started when possible, and services that can be activated when needed are only activated, including their dependencies, as required.

Now, the the thing is, you seem to be on an archaic Unixoid distribution (probably an archaic linux distro?) that relies on init-scripts. And these only support a fixed start order and have no support for dependencies or on-demand activation.

You hit **the** classical argument for why the classical init system needs to be reworked!

So, whatever Linux distro you're (probably) using: you identified the problem; the solution is to use a boot manager that actually deserves that name. Don't be shy – update your Linux to something that follows what we've all learned over the last 20 years of Linux design!
You'll notice that when you start using for example a plain, stock debian, that startup times are better (very much contrary to what proponents of older init systems will tell you about "bloat" that they see at every corner without it actually being there) and the boot process is easier to modify.

Comment: Ancient and archaic no, pre-systemd yes. Support for dependencies, yes too, btw. Upgrading the distro is not an option for various reasons that are not relevant here.

Comment: OK, I'm surprised you have an /etc/init.d based boot management that supports dependencies? You then should obviously use that! (**Very** curious how that works! The classical sysv/init.d boot system literally just cannot deal with dependencies.)

Comment: And I'm not referring to systemd alone, sure, that's the common option and I'd generally recommend it, but if some other sensible boot manager does what you want: go for it. It's just that nearly every time I meet someone who is very proud that their distro doesn't use systemd, they act as if the problem solved by systemd don't exist, or needn't be solved – you're clearly not one of these people (you have one of the problems solved by systemd, and you say it!), so that's refreshing.

Comment: So, now the question is: what boot system do you have if it's neither systemd nor classical sysv-init? You'll have to tell us, otherwise, how are we supposed to help you with your boot process? Please **edit** your question to tell us about your distro and the boot system it uses (I can't be of much help; I don't know any other system that uses /etc/init.d aside from the mostly obsolete sysv-init, which doesn't support boot order dependencies, just absolute ordering)

Comment: "your request for your graphical system to start before netatalk has finished starting" - that is in fact not the problem, rather the opposite. The display manager starts before the netatalk startup has even been initiated. I understand there's little I can do about that (maybe rename the init script to zzkdm :) ) For now I've tweaked the netatalk script so it does the lengthy launch operation in the background.

Comment: wait? You just said that your boot system supports dependencies, and now you claim there's nothing you can do but rename the display-manager-starting script? That is not at all dependency-ordered booting, that is the dysfunctional (as sadly seen here) static-order boot!

Comment: I'm on a "FrankUbuntu" 14.04, lots of updates of my own via PPAs or in a parallel tree but the init system is the same as Debian used. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80785/70384 for how it handles interdependencies

Comment: Yes, I could also edit the kdm launch script so it waits for the last script. That may in fact be the surer way to achieve what I want.

Comment: And yes, I know why systemd exists. Doesn't mean I like its complexity so the more recent set-ups I maintain run Devuan.

Comment: Again, I did specifically say you're not forced to use systemd when you have a system that does your booting. Really confused now; debian does use systemd, contrary to what you say in your comment! What's a frankUbuntu 14.04? if it's a Ubuntu derivate: Ubuntu 14.04 has been obsolete for about four years now, and only is supported when you buy Canonical's strange paid security updates. Didn't Ubuntu 14.04 use the quite strange proprietary Upstart boot manager? That was quite complex to administrate :-)

Comment: I specifically remember upstart as one of the things where it was universally praised when Canonical pivoted Ubuntu from a proprietary solution, and by now they've even taken down the upstart documentation (bad move, IMHO, why do that?) (and debian never used upstart, either, so very confused what system you actually have?)

Comment: "FrankUbuntu" is my term for a Frankenstein Ubuntu, with lots of patches as I said before. I didn't touch the boot system though, it's a bit of a mix. There's upstart indeed which provides /sbin/init but there's also a rudimentare systemd implementation that seems to be there mostly because software started expecting it.

Comment: But what is it, specifically? We really can't help you when we don't know what you're using. You're not even giving us anything to guess!

Comment: I suppose the files in /etc/init.d are processed by /sbin/init, so upstart. But I can't seem to find if that's indeed the case.

Comment: Sorry, if you can't describe and link to documentation of the boot system of your self-patched operating system, I'm all out of ideas how anybody could possibly help you :(